# PHP require works only once after clearing APC Cache, then 500 error. Why?

Tags: php, apc

I've got an APC issue. 
Parent.php is including another file with a relative path. e.g.

require_once 'child.php';

If I clear apc_cache, then load Parent.php, it works.
But on the subsequent load, it fails. Dying on require_once 'child.php'.

Clearly the relative path, when saved to apc_cache, is not being translated properly on the next load...

apc.include_once_override is turned off, so it isn't that.

What else could it be?

Editing to add the error:
PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required
'path/to/file.php'

Answer (score 3):

If you have `apc.stat=0` in your config, your problem could be related to this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61854

Setting `apc.stat=1` in my PHP config fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Haha sorry, should've checked the date more carefully. Perhaps this'll help someone else at some point :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a stretch, but I saw issues related to that when you're working hard-linked files, which may be cached through a different path.

Regardless, sounds like a bug. Are you on the latest PHP and APC versions? If so, post a bug report.

Comment: Yes, it can be cached through a different path... How did you resolve your problem? BTW: PHP Version => 5.2.16

Comment: joedevon: I most likely worked around the issue by explicitly specifying paths.

Comment: Turns out it can't be that. When I clear cache it fails right on the first time...this is a test box... So without an alternate path calling it, it fails already.

Answer (score 0):

i once had a strange issue with relative paths on APC too. The problem was it died with an fatal error, I'd solved this issue by following the [thread here](http://markmail.org/message/6gc6yownk4rvdj73#query%3a%5bapc-error%5d%20Cannot%20redeclare%20class+page:1+mid:6gc6yownk4rvdj73+state%3aresults):

In my project the following lines got it to work:

```
// Realpath needed to fix problem with APC
require_once realpath($fullPath);
```

Comment: I'm having a different error. But it might not hurt to add realpath. I'll let you know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, downloading the correct version for my php version solved this issue. You can find a bunch of versions here ( if running on windows ): http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html